# How to give file name when using NewHadoopRDD?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to use the **newAPIHadoopRDD** function in Spark, but I see that there is no argument in the constructor which takes file's name. So, how to set the filename in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is configured using `org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration` and details depend on the `InputFormat` you use. For example `TextInputFormat` uses `mapred.input.dir`.

In general if you want use file based source use `newAPIHadoopFile`.

Comment: So, basically, I just my file(s) in a directory, say "my_input_dir" and then set val c = new Configuration(sc.hadoopConfiguration);
c.set("mapred.input.dir", "my_input_dir");